# For a checkout page progress tracker, is it considered bad practice to skip to step 2 (if the user is already signed in)?

Tags: checkout, progress

For a checkout page progress tracker, if the first step is login/register, is it considered bad practice to skip to step 2 (because the user is already logged in when they get to checkout)?

Would it be better to remove the "step 1 login/register" from the progress tracker, if you detect that the user is already logged in when they get to the checkout page?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to move registration to the end of the checkout process and make it optional. Then it wouldn't be part of the progress tracker at all. See [Should registration be optional on an e-commerce site?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/should-registration-be-optional-on-an-e-commerce-site)

Comment: The registration/login is a required step. The purchase is for a premium account, where the user must be logged in in order for the purchase to be linked to his/her account.

Comment: Generally this would follow an upgrade/downgrade paradigm, not a checkout paradigm. In either case, login as a step does not make sense to me, though I do not know enough about your situation to provide examples or data backing up my opinion.

Comment: Guess I'm using the "checkout" term somewhat loosely; the user is upgrading their account, but they must go through steps similar to a checkout (login/register, payment info). Also, if the user is not logged in, how can you associate their purchase for a premium account, with their current account?

Comment: Can you provide a user story of a user who has an account upgrading from a logged out state? What would drive them to upgrade if they are not logged in?

Comment: Sure can! The user lands on the overview page, which outlines the details and benefits about the premium accounts (part of a fund-raiser promotion). This page can be viewed by anyone (most of the site can be viewed without logging in as well, except for certain areas/actions). The user can then click the "purchase" button to get a premium account. Here, they are either prompted to login/register if they aren't already logged in. Then, they enter payment information and complete the purchase.

Comment: If the login/register is not part of the process, then the overview page will be limited to only logged-in users, which is needlessly limiting a part of the site (containing information about the benefits of the premium accounts).

Comment: You skipped the most important part of the story, which is why would an existing user land on the overview page. What prompts the existing user to want to learn about upgrading?

Presumably they are trying to complete some action (add more users for example) that prompts them to upgrade, in which case they are logged in. Or they get an email that they are over quota, in which case the link in the email has a token that logs them in.

Comment: During the promotion, the sidebar will prominently display a link for the premium account overview. There will also be a video covering the fund-raiser with links (which will be shared on various outlets). Social media promotions will also link to either the video or the overview page. So many new users, as well as current users who are not signed in, will be able to see the promotion overview page.

Answer (score 0):

If a user must login/register in order to make a purchase then there is no need to collect anything from them until they are logged in.

If they are already logged in then there is no need to even show a login step so I would remove Step 1.

The best UI is no UI.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not bad practice. I think that reverse is true. Your customer will be motivated. You will make him feel like he is getting done with the thing faster.

Take a look at
[Goal gradient effect](http://coglode.com/gems/goal-gradient-effect)