# Checkout flow for buying as guest

Tags: e-commerce, workflow, checkout

I'm working on an e-commerce web site and was reading more about the checkout process. I've found [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/should-registration-be-optional-on-an-e-commerce-site), talking about the benefits of not asking users to create an account on the web site in order to buy something. Instead, the advice is to let them buy and, later on, try to interact with that user, trying to create an account. This point is very clear to me, but I'm still in doubt on how to best design the initial step, where I need to, first, identify if the user is a new user or if he already has an account.

> <sub>In my case, the user has 2 options to create a new account: E-mail/password or Facebook login.</sub>

When the user clicks on the button to initate the checkout process, I have these options:

1. Identify: Check if user has an account or if it's first time buying;
2. Address: Fill in an address or use one (if avaliable);
3. Payment: Credit card payments;
4. Confirm: Screen to show a confirm message (Congrats, your purchase was successful);

The "Identify" step is where I'm in doubt. For example, what would be a good design to ask for the users login credentials or just identify his name/e-mail(?) to get in touch later on?

#### Option 1

For this, I'm working with this initial mock design:

[image]

My concerns with this design would be:

- I feel like I'm already showing a lot of information all at once;
- If the user is a new user and just fill his initial data (email and name) do I need to validate his e-mail? For example, a "confirm e-mail" field in order to avoid typos?
- What if the user doesn't mind creating a new account?

---

#### Option 2

Another option would be to have a button **"New user"** or **"Create an account"** and then, based on the option the user selects, the view would change (hide/show the proper form based on his choice).

[image]

I feel like the second option is better, the design is a bit cleaner, but it also feels like it adds a next step (e.g. step *1.1*) during the checkout process.

---

#### Option 3

The third option would be to treat the **"New user"** and **"Create account"** as one single case, I mean, do not show the **"Create account"** option here, just guide throught the **"New user"** process, and on the confirmation screen asks if the user wants to provide a password to access his information in the future.

---

Any other advice or cosideration are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: My non-research-backed opinion: option 2 is comprehensive, clean, and makes sense at first-glance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also currently designing an e-commerce website and I'm using something similar to your second option (layout wise).

Once the user selects "Checkout as a guest" they are redirected to the next step - Shipping information. Don't make an extra step just to ask for name and email. You can get this information in the shipping step.

If the user selects guest checkout, then you are safe to assume that they don't want to register an account. And by having this extra step you will confuse them - it does seem like a registration process.

Ask for name and email in shipping step, you can even clarify the need for this information with some text like *"Well use this information to send you the receipt or to contact you about the shipment"*. It makes sense for the user to provide this information there, as it's related to buying/receiving the goods.

After the user is finished with the purchase, you can then ask them if they want to register the account. You will have all the necessary information and a simple password field will be enough to complete the account.

Comment: That's a very small change but I think can improve the design and flow a lot! Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Just finished working on this feature as well.

The longer your checkout is the more abandonment you'll see.
Therefore I wouldn't add an additional identity step.
A way of solving it could be adding an email field at the first step of checkout (as a part of the delivery step) once the users insert their email you can identify if they have an account under this email address or not.

In case they are a guest user simply let them proceed through checkout.
After they successfully complete the checkout flow, allow them to create an account by just adding a password, since they have already provided an email address.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest making any checkout flow as short as possible while still meeting the needs/functions of both the customer and the host site.

Also, I've found in many recent UX labs that during the checkout stage, a short tool-tip explaining why you are asking for personal details (email, phone number etc) can inject another level of trust which ultimately helps improve conversions