# What's best for a Social Network app first open? Registration needed to view to content or not?

Tags: registration, social-media, accounts, onboarding

It is optimal to not force the user to create an account on an E-commerce website/application since the objective is to increase the purchases, as noted [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/should-registration-be-optional-on-an-e-commerce-site?noredirect=1&lq=1).

What about a Social Network application? When an user downloads the app, it is better to let him access the content (like posts and other profiles, while obviously limiting what he can do without an account, like commenting or messaging) and when he wants he can create an account, or it is better to just present him a onboard page to create an account when he first opens the app?
For a Social Network the objective is to increase the number of accounts present and monthly active users, so what onboard approach is more performant?

If I recall correctly, the TikTok app used to let the users access the content before an account was created, now it is necessary to view videos and access the rest of the app. But we are no way near the amount of users TikTok has.

Answer (score 1):

Personal opinion, my user experience, I hate that Facebook and Instagram limit my view without an account. There is a food truck near me that only operates using both of those platforms, and I refuse to make an account.

Because of this, I am never able to see their menu updates or where they are going to be on a given day.

That said, I think there is something to the fact that a user should be able to 'see' all of the things that they are missing out on, which in turn will convince them to sign up.

Meaning, if I constantly see all my friends sharing pictures through links, I should be able to access them without an account, I just don't get the opportunity to comment or interact with the content.

If we use my food truck dilemma, it's more of an inconvenince to me, because I would end up only making the account to look that one piece of information up.

I guess it depends on how predatory and forceful you want to be with your consumers and potential consumer base.

Comment: Thanks for your personal insight!